# How to incorporate two dependent variable in one noUiSlider?

Tags: nouislider

I want to put two dependent variable in one slider(not range just single value). For example i have test scores and GPA variables that shows in single slider with first initialization as:-

Test Scores (100%) |----------------------|-----------------------| GPA (100%)

The middle pip is where the drag button should be with 50% as initial value. When i move to the right the test scores variable must be increased and GPA should decrease. Similarly when moving left the test scores must decrease increasing GPA.

How do i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what the values at the 'edges' should be, but assuming the two values should sum to 100%, you could add/subtract from 50, like so:

```
slider.Link().to(testScore, function( value ){
    $(this).html( 50 - Number(value) );
});

slider.Link().to(GPA, function( value ){
    $(this).html( 50 + Number(value) );
});
```

I've set up [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/j0cpn6aL/) on jsFiddle that shows this in action.